# change the color of the area if current time is equal to row time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i got the currenttime value and if the currenttime is equal to the row time of the workday planner,it should display a color.
if current time is more than the row time ,the text area should display a different color.
if current time is less than the row time ,then text area should display a different color.

```
<div id="9" class="row">
        <div class="col-2 col-md-1 hour text-center py-3">9AM</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 col-md-10 description" rows="3" id="txtarea"> </textarea>
        <button class="btn saveBtn col-2 col-md-1" aria-label="save">
          <i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="10" class="row">
        <div class="col-2 col-md-1 hour text-center py-3">10AM</div>
        <textarea class="col-8 col-md-10 description" rows="3" id="txtarea"> </textarea>
        <button class="btn saveBtn col-2 col-md-1" aria-label="save">
          <i class="fas fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
```

```
var rowlist =document.querySelectorAll(".row");


var rowlistarr= Array.from(rowlist);
var index=0;


function timeblock()

{
  for(index=0;index<rowlistarr.length;index++){

    if(time =rowlistarr){
      var areacolor=document.getElementById("#textarea").innerHTML;

     areacolor.style.color="Yellow";
    }
else if(time<rowlistarr)
{
  var areacolor=document.getElementById("#textarea").innerHTML;

     areacolor.style.color="Yellow";

}
else if(time>rowlistarr)
{

  var areacolor=document.getElementById("#textarea").innerHTML;

  areacolor.style.color="Yellow";

}

    //console.log(rowlist[index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no element with the ID `#textarea`. Even if we were to excuse your confusion of [`getElementById`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) with [`querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), there still isn’t even an element with the ID `textarea`. Duplicate IDs are invalid. How do you expect this to work? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. [Validate your HTML](//html5.validator.nu).

Comment: `if(time = rowlistarr)` isn’t a comparison. Please see [What is the difference between the `=` and `==` operators and what is `===`?](/q/11871616/4642212). Use linters like [ESLint](//eslint.org/play) or [JSHint](//jshint.com) to find problems with your code immediately. Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/4642212).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Too many errors to provide a useful answer, as included above, but also:  `=` isn't `==`, duplicate IDs, `textarea`!=`txtarea`, `.innerHTML.style`, no definition of `time`, then, if all of these were fixed - your `==`,`>`, and `<` *all* set to yellow.   Start by checking your browser console for errors (F12).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `innerHTML` property at the end of your `getElementById()` call.

instead of

```js
var areacolor=document.getElementById("#textarea").innerHTML;
```

use

```js
var areacolor=document.getElementById("#textarea")
```